# Government Publications on LinkedIn or Personal Website

Tags: ethics, work-experience, linkedin

I work for a government agency which evaluates programs at other agencies. The end result of one of our projects is a publication that is publicly available. Each project involves a team of up to 5 staff members who work collaboratively.

Some of our projects are interesting enough that I would like to add them on my personal website or LinkedIn.  However, given that they are collaborative reports I'm not sure if I should. I wouldn't want to unfairly take credit for others' work.

I looked around at my coworkers' profiles to get an idea what is normal.  About 80-90% don't have any professional web presence, and the remainder have only minimal presence.

Comment: Does the report name the authors? Would you name the authors of the report when you post it?

Comment: @Brandin - The inside cover of the report lists the authors. On LinkedIn, I think I can only add authors who are also on LinkedIn. Most of them aren't.

Comment: Use "et al" to indicate multiple authors. E.g. "Prepared by indigochild et al."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an unusual situation.  Most of the work you'll ever do is collaborative, yet you need to "take credit" in some form on your resume.

It's certainly a good idea to share the results of your work when it can be made available, because this is so much stronger evidence of what you can do than simply describing it.  So I would definitely put some reports on your page.

In addition, I suggest you **describe your specific contribution to the report** in the accompanying description.

Besides clarifying that the report is not all your work, this also gives you a chance to highlight your specific skills and experience as evidenced by this work.

Answer (score 1):

As you'll already know, anything that you produce for the US Government is public domain unless it falls into one of the exception categories (eg if it's secret). So there is no copyright restriction on you publishing it on your website or LinkedIn.

As they are collaborative reports, I would mention that they are collaborative reports. If there is space, maybe credit the people or departments who were involved. Most people will realize that government reports of any magnitude are not written by a single person.